# Accidentally damaged the power button's Circuit Board Cable now Laptop turns off randomly

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply

I was cleaning my laptop inspiron 15R(N5520) and i accidently damaged the connecter ribbon pins of the power button under the keyboard.Now my laptop turns off randomly and i have to tinker with the connector pins to start it again.Is there any other solution than buying a new power button board or is it due to any other problem.

Comment: It is not due to another problem, you will need to either fix or replace the connector pins, I have my doubts a "new button" will achieve that unless the connector pins go to the button.

Comment: I was able to straighten the cable which was the problem and it worked but after a few hours my pc started acting strange,first it just turned off and then when i pressed the power button it starts and turns off with a slight click noise after a sec after that i cleaned the motherboard and assembled the laptop again after i did the static discharge and now it's working fine but i feel it will happen again is there a reason for that shutdown issue?